# How can I stop ASP.NET Identity from Deleting a role if there's a UserId that has that role?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity

Here is the SQL for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);
```

Can someone help me. What I would like is for when there is a user that has been assigned to a role then I would like an attempt to delete the role to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue arises from the line `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
This line means that all records with foreign keys that connect to the record to be deleted will themselves be deleted.

You probably want `ON DELETE NO ACTION`. This will do what you want. You should be able to find whether anything was deleted by the return value of the query call (- It should be an integer containing the number of lines changed).